# Flutter Listview Filter Not Rebuilding List on Type

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am fetching a list with StreamProvider, it renders the list fine on screen.

When I type in the search box, the list is not rebuilt, but I can see the list items being filtered in the list as I type. Why is the list not rebuilding on the screen? I have included as little code as possible.

I have filtered lists before this way, but by using a future builder where the filter method is above the build context. But I don't know if this is the problem, this example below works for others and I am very confused. Spent two full days on this already.

Please help find why the list does not rebuild when I search. I hope my example is sufficient enough, I will gladly provide any detail. Thank you

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<NameListData> nameListData = Provider.of<List<NameListData>>(context);  // <- PROVIDER LIST

    List filteredNames = [];         // <- FULL LIST RENDERING FINE ON SCREEN

    List userNamesList = filteredNames = nameListData; 

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {             // <-- FILTER TEXT FIELD AND METHOD
                          value.toLowerCase();
                          setState(() {
                            filteredNames = userNamesList
                                .where((name) => name.userName
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                                .toList();
                  
                          });
                        },
                        decoration: kInputSearchDecoration.copyWith(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            
            Expanded(
              child: (filteredNames != null)
                  ? ListView.builder(                         // <--LISTVIEW BUILDER
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: filteredNames.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0, left: 6.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              navigateToRoutes(filteredNames[index].userName);
                
                            },


....
```

Comment: I am now following this and will update my answer if it works as it should: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333739/search-filter-listview-with-provider-and-model-classes

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make this work was add the .where filter to the end of the provided list.

```
List< NameListData > nameListData = Provider.of<List< NameListData >>(context)
    .where((crags) =>
        crags.listName.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()))
    .toList();
```